# about selecting all visible elements in editmode？

Tags: scripting

I checked some information and got the following code：

```
def visibleElement(context, bm):
        area = context.area
        spc = context.space_data
        sel_mode = context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode[:]
        show_xray_wireframe = spc.shading.show_xray_wireframe
        spc.shading.show_xray_wireframe = False
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False, use_expand=False, type='FACE')
        bpy.ops.view3d.select_box(xmin=0,xmax=area.width,ymin=0,ymax=area.height,wait_for_input=False,mode='SET')
        context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode = sel_mode
        verts = [bmv for bmv in bm.verts if bmv.select]
        edges = [bme for bme in bm.edges if bme.select]
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        spc.shading.show_xray_wireframe = show_xray_wireframe
        return verts, edges
```

Is this the only solution？To be honest, I don’t really want to use select_box, but there seems to be no other solution.

Comment: AFAIK using box select operator as above in edit mode is probably the simplest, and likely quickest way to do this.  Other methods would involve eliminating geometry by  looking at normals, and further eliminating via raycast or some such in case of occluding geometry.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot